# How can I force CircleCI to re-run the workflows when a new PR is created?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

Any new commits I push to my Github repository automatically triggers the CircleCI workflow which is great.

When I create a new pull request, the statuses of the workflows are reflected in my PR. All of these are fine.

However, I have recently added code coverage in my workflow to automatically post comments to my PR after the checks. If I didn't create the PR immediately after I push my commit and had only created the PR after the workflows have finished running for the commit, the bot is not going to post any coverage comments to my PR because the workflow has already been run for that commit. The workflows don't get re-run again when I create a new PR with that commit.

Is there anyway to force CircleCI to re-run the workflows again when a new PR is created?

Comment: If you're using danger to post comments on the PR, they encouraged allowing running workflows with pull requests only through CircleCI option "Only build pull requests". Otherwise, you might face what you're facing now